# Cakephp 3.1 have issues with PHP7.2

Tags: cakephp-3.0, php-7.2

I have develop my web application by using cakephp 3.1. My service provider has update the php version to 7.2. Now my application is not work well, as it was working with PHP5.6, Its showing different warnings with `debug=true;` and the big problem is its not showing line which have some problem, if some is there. Here is warning message.

`Warning: count() [function.count]: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in D:\xampp7\htdocs\bighris\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\QueryCompiler.php on line 115`

In case some errors are there its not showing it, in the following way, there I can't find the line number and the file which have the problem.

https://www.screencast.com/t/qIQB1YIW

Please help me to solve the issue, Thanks

Comment: Click on the first entry of the stack trace on the left hand side, it will open context information on the right hand side, and a link that says "_toggle arguments_"... click that link and it will show you which file the autoloader tried to include, that will be the file where the syntax error can be found. You can also update your error template to a newer version so that it outputs the file and line number, see **https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.7.1/src/Template/Error/error500.ctp#L25-L28**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Cakephp github issues:

**PHP 7.2 has changed count's behavior**
 that's why you are getting errors.

[PHP 7.2 has changed count's behavior causing problems with QueryCompiler](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10862)

You can follow the below link or change your PHP version to 7.1 or less to resolve this issue.

[Stop warnings when using count in QueryCompiler in PHP 7.2](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/10864)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are passing some wrong data to count function, guess you are passing some query directly to count. Or something like that.
If you may show the code of the controller you are facing issue it may be a great help.

Answer (score -1):

there is solution for you....
2020-09-30 06:22:30 Warning: Warning (2): count() [function.count]: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in [D:\xampp\htdocs\gym_master\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\QueryCompiler.php, line 126]

please check your php version...

Comment: OP has already mentioned that the PHP version was updated.